# can't install matplotlib on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

After I installed anaconda and installed matplotlib successfully from anaconda prompt , i still cannot see the package in my editor (import fails).
Maybe I did not set some env variable?

I'm using eclipse with a PyDev IDE.

Comment: Did you try re configuring the interpreter in the eclipse project properties?

Comment: Doesn't Anaconda come with matplotlib installed?